# The negative form of "extreme"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, negation

What is the negative form of the word "extreme" for this context:

> Temperature/climate insignificantly influences the production of honey due to
>   the  ______(non-extreme)______  temperature during monsoon season.

Comment: You might consider using thesaurus.com for future reference :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common antonym of *extreme*,
in contexts ranging from weather to politics, is ***moderate***:

> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/moderate):
>
> - Average in amount, intensity, quality, or degree.  
>     *‘we walked at a moderate pace’*
>
>   (of a person, party, or policy) not radical
>     or excessively right- or left-wing.  
>     *‘a moderate reform program’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=moderate):
>
> 1. Being within reasonable limits;
>      not excessive or extreme:    a moderate price.
>
>    Not violent or subject to extremes;
>      mild or calm; temperate:  a moderate climate.
>
>    - Of medium or average quantity or extent.
>
>      Of limited or average quality; mediocre.
>
>    Opposed to radical or extreme views or measures,
>      especially in politics or religion.
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/moderate_1):
>
>   neither very great nor very small
>     in amount, size, strength, or degree
>   *Cook the spinach over a moderate heat.*
>   *A moderate earthquake shook the San Francisco bay area
>     this afternoon.*
>   *We need more housing for moderate-income families.*
>   *This is a new drug for treating mild to moderate depression.*